# How to do this Simple Calculation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to do this Simple Calculation using JavaScript ? Because i am a beginner.

i want to calculate the value in the same input field.

e.g In the input field, I type the value such as " 3+4*2 ", then i click the button, the **same input field** will show the result like "11".

Here is my code, but not work.

my input type = "text" and id ="expr"

my button type = "button" , value = "Calculate", onclick = "getAnswer();"

Here is my javascript code.

```
function getAnswer(){

    val = eval(document.expr.value);
    document.expr.value = val; 

}
```

but i'm not work.

Comment: `eval` is not a proper function to use in a calculator.

Comment: eval('var result = '+document.getElementById('expr').value +';');

Comment: To galchen: Sorry, i tried this but not work.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: umm, yes. look at the answer

Comment: What I wanted to say is that it's not necessary to put more than the expression itself inside the `eval(..)` argument.

Comment: To ThiefMaster, in StackOverflow, would you like become a program friend ? HAHA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.expr` most likely does not exist.

Give your input tag an id and use `document.getElementById('blah')` instead or use `document.forms.FORMNAME.expr` if the field is inside a form.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/kRdJH/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calc(){
        //eval('var result = '+document.getElementById('expr').value +';');
        // EDIT:
        var result = eval(document.getElementById('expr').value);
        alert(result);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="expr" />
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="calc();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need in putting more than the actual expression in the `eval` call. It returns the value of the expression you evaluated.

Comment: Right. If `eval` is given a statement, it executes it. If it is given an `expression`, it evaluates it.